# Is it possible to restrict a user from interacting with a specific component?

Tags: aem

We want to prevent a user group from editing components like `colctr` in AEM 5.6.1. Is there a way to restict user access to specific components? It looks like the you can prevent a user/group from being able to enter design mode by locking them out of `/etc`, so it is possible to change all of the dialogs to design dialogs to get the restriction. There must be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: You could change the acl rules on that specific component for your target usergroup. e.g. take away there write rights

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was something conflicting with my user and group, so it seemed more complicated than it actually was. You can just deny on each component through useradmin.

Answer (score 0):

ACLs to control permissions, even down to component level:
https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/boilerplates.html#Preventing Changes to Boilerplate Content

Answer (score 0):

ACL won't help since components are read using an admin session.
As far as I know you can't prevent the component to show up in the sidekick on a per user basis. But what you could do is write a SlingPostProcessor (Executed after each post request) and check if the user has the right to handle the current resource.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/SlingPostProcessor.html